# Angular Emit event only if method does not get called for a certain timespan

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, event-handling

I have an input field that calls the method `inputChanged` as soon as the input changes.
It looks like this:

```
<custom-input (altered)="inputChanged($event)"
              ...
              >
```

```
@Output()
public changed: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

...

public inputChanged(value: string): void {
    this.changed.emit(value + ...)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to only trigger `this.changed.emit(value + ...)` if the last time `inputChanged` has been called is more than 1000ms ago.

So the sequence could look like this.

`inputChanged('t')`
-> 100ms
-> `inputChanged('te')`
-> 200ms
-> `inputChanged('tes')`
-> 50ms
-> `inputChanged('test')`
-> 1000ms
-> `this.changed.emit(value + ...)`

I have found stuff like debounceTime in rxjs but I don't know how to use this in my context as I am not allowed to alter the input field compoment itself. The implementation has to be in the component that uses the input field.

Can anybody help me here?

FYI: I am using Angular 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun fact: a regular `Observable` can be used as an `@Output()` instead of an `EventEmitter`.

In your component, introduce a Subject to push values through, then expose an Observable that uses `debounceTime` to control emissions.

```
class YourComponent {

  private value$ = new Subject();

  @Output() changed = this.value$.pipe(debounceTime(1000));

  public inputChanged(value: string): void {
      this.value$.next(value + ...)
  }

}
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75544767?devtoolsHeight=75&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Fmy.component.ts) demo.